# Ocultar texto entre chaves em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso ocultar um texto que esteja entre chaves na minha div

Ex:

```
<div> Hello {World} </div>
```

Comment: Sabe expressão regular? É uma das maneiras de se fazer isso...

Comment: Adicione uma tag span em volta ao texto que queres oculta inserindo um id ou class, e em seguida basta manipular o texto com JS. Exemplo: <div> Hello <span id="text">{World}</span> </div>

Comment: Seria tão facil assim, mas não posso editar essa div :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [Expressão Regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```js
var text = $("div").text();
$("div").html('').append(text.replace(/(\s\{.*?\})/, ''))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Hello {World} </div>
```

Comment: Oi Netinho, ótimo ajudou muito! e seu eu querer replicar pra varias divs?

Comment: @Josimara, se suas divs estiver do mesmo jeito da div da pergunta, você poderá usar o Jquery.each() para varre as divs. Fiz um exemplo, caso seja o que tu queres eu edito a resposta. Veja o exemplo executando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/1p5m48wq/3/

Comment: Isso mesmo ótimo, valeuu!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tente com essa expressão regular:

```js
let getDiv = document.querySelector('.teste').innerHTML;

let newTeste = getDiv.replace(/(\s\{.*?\})/, '');

document.querySelector('.teste').innerHTML = newTeste;
```

```html
<div class="teste">Hello {World} !</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pega o texto da div, faz um replace usando expressão regular

```js
var textoDaDiv = $("div").text();  

$("div").text(textoDaDiv.replace(/ *\{[^)]*\} */g, ""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Hello {World} </div>
```